# Why is the Kitzur so much more popular than the Chayey Adam?

Tags: halacha, history, jewish-books, posek-psak-decisor-ruling

The Chayey Adam was considered to be the "popular kitzur Shulchan Aruch" for almost a century before the "Kitzur Shulchan Aruch" was printed. Why did people stop learning the Chayey Adam and switch to the Kitzur?

Comment: Maybe because the name sounds more simple for the regular Baal HaBos.

Comment: They must have been learning something before the Chayey Adam, and they've since moved on to other things since the Kitzur.

Comment: Why is the S"'A more popular than the Tur?

Comment: Why is the Rambam more popular than the Rif?

Comment: Why is the iPad more popular than the Kindle Fire HD?

Comment: @SethJ Re: iPad...come on! That's obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the CA only covers (mainly) Orach Chayim whereas KSA covers all four parts of Shulchan Aruch.

Comment: Chochmas Adam?...

Comment: The Chochmas Adam is only mainly Yore Dea'ah without Hilchos Challah which he writes in his Sefer Sha'arei Tzedek which covers Dinim of Israel like Teruma etc. But he does not have on all parts of SA.

Comment: So according to this, everyone's going to ditch Mishna Berura for Aruch haShulchan in a couple years?

Comment: People already looking for an upgraded mishna brurah.